# VPN-Always-on VPN disconnects WiFi on my tablet

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, vpn

I'm trying to connect to my work vpn with my Galaxy Tab S2. I can connect just fine with the same settings on my Samsung Note 5.

Using : L2TP/IPSec PSK.

When I put the same settings in for my tablet it says "Unsuccessful". But the drop down on the screen says "VPN is Connected" However there is no duration. Sent and Received show info was exchanged. Our network guy can also see this activity. This is with Always-on selected.

When Always-on is selected it cuts the wifi out and says "wifi is connected, but there is no internet"

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: I bought a new laptop and it solved all my vpn problems. My laptop wasn't disconnecting properly. woops!